# Is there any way to filter objects using _pickBy() for float numbers

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I am trying to filter one Object and filtering to display only the version greater than 9.8 by using _pickBy lodash method. But it is not working as expected. My code is below,

```
let test_obj= {
 "version-1":{
      "path":"abcd",
      "version":"9.1"
   },
   "version-2":{
      "path":"efgh",
      "version":"9.9.1"
   },
   "version-3":{
      "path":"bbbbbb",
      "version":"9.10.0"
   },
   "version-4":{
      "path":"cccccc",
      "version":"9.9.0"
   },
   "version-5":{
      "path":"kkkkkkk",
      "version":"9.8"
   }
}

let output = _.pickBy(test_obj, (v,k) => v.version === "" || parseFloat(v.version) >= parseFloat(9.8));
```

The output for the above code is,

```
{
       "version-2":{
          "path":"efgh",
          "version":"9.9.1"
       },
       "version-4":{
          "path":"cccccc",
          "version":"9.9.0"
       },
       "version-5":{
          "path":"kkkkkkk",
          "version":"9.8"
       }
    }
```

JS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ufzh7631/

It should add `"version-3"` as well, because it is greater than 9.8. But it is omitting 9.10.0.
Is there any way to achieve this. Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: try to use .toFixed(2), it will keep 2 decimal places

Comment: .toFixed() is also not working. Please check JSfiddle link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with `numeric: true` in the options parameter

```
v.version.localeCompare("9.8", undefined, { 'numeric': true }) >= 0
```

This works even when there are more than 1 decimal points in the version like `9.8.1`

```js
let test_obj = {
  "version-1": {
    "path": "abcd",
    "version": "9.1"
  },
  "version-2": {
    "path": "efgh",
    "version": "9.9.1"
  },
  "version-3": {
    "path": "bbbbbb",
    "version": "9.10.0"
  },
  "version-4": {
    "path": "cccccc",
    "version": "9.9.0"
  },
  "version-5": {
    "path": "kkkkkkk",
    "version": "9.8"
  }
}

let output = _.pickBy(
  test_obj,
  v => v.version === "" || v.version.localeCompare("9.8", undefined, { 'numeric': true }) >= 0);

console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```